# How to display Images from One Project to Another Project using ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two modules in one solution: Project1 and Project2.
    Project1 has an Images Folder like below

```
Project1->Images-> 1.jpg
                   2.jpg
                   3.jpg
```

Project2 has a file called Default.aspx. I want able to display the images from Project 1 in the `Default.aspx` file from Project2.

```
Default.aspx code: 


<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <img src="..//1.jpg" height="100" width="100" alt="2" />
</div>
</form>
```

Thanks,
Somu

Comment: It doesn't matter where the images are within your projects, when the web app is running in iis then they need to be in a location the web server can access. Something like a post build operation that copied the images to an appropriate folder would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, Please give me some example.  But i tried below code  its not working                                                                                                  <img src="../Project1/Images/1.jpg" height="100" width="100" alt="2" />